# uitableview lagging - addition of image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

my `UITableView` is lagging because I have included an image -

```
cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"]]];
```

Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The allocation of the image could be your problem. You should probably not do it in your cellForRowAtIndexPath because it's an expensive operation.
Depending on your use case try to allocate and cache the images before or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` which has internal caching built in. This is especially useful if you're re-using the same image a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a memory leak by using that method. You're calling `alloc` on an `UIImage` and I don't think you release it (I don't have your code, so I don't know). You should just use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
                stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"]]];
```

Or more simply, just use

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```